# Saving files and pictures as one file in delphi

Tags: delphi

I am doing some fun project of mine and it uses alot of images and file(.txt and such).  My knowledge about Delphi is somewhat limited because I'm only in grade 12 now.. 
I want to save the folder with all the pictures in as n specific file that my program can extract all the images and files. (It's hard to explain, I'll give a example of what I have in mind) 
Eg. My program take all the images and files and save it as a .dat , so that it is only the .exe and the .dat . 
And when I run my program I can see all the images, and can change the data in my .txt files, in my program

Comment: if you want to join and split files you should maybe look at concatenating files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use container format, for instance ZIP, if you wish. But it is probably easier to add your images to the project as resources. That way the executable file is completely self-contained. Extract the resources using `TResourceStream`, for example.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a ZIP-File using the [TZipFile class](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/System.Zip.TZipFile), if your version of Delphi has it available (I think the class is available since Delphi 2010 IIRC).

You do not need to call the file `*.zip` if you want to use `*.dat` as the extension, it will work also.

At runtime you can extract the files and show them in your program.

Comment: There are many Zip implementations for Delphi. ZipForge is another good one.

Comment: It would be somewhat pointless to write a Delphi program to make the zip file. You'd use delphi to extract it.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I will go and try it. Hope I can get it working